# ongoing tax implications of 1031 exchange out of California

Tags: taxes, california, 1031-exchange

I'm considering a 1031 exchange of a rental property to a different property out of California.

I assume that I will owe tax to California if I sell the property after the 1031. But will I have to do anything additional on my yearly CA taxes, or perhaps just some reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to file the [CA FTB Form 3840](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/reporting-like-kind-exchanges.html) until the deferred gain is recognized.